# Best way to find out distinct item in the big list

Tags: c#, .net, list, c#-4.0, collections

I have a following collection, it has more than 500000 items in it.

```
List<Item> MyCollection = new List<Item>();
```

and type:

```
class Item
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I want to return a list of items having distinct Name. i.e. to find out distinct item based on name.

What are the possible ways & which would be best in terms of time & memory. Although both are important however less time has more priority over memory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5970996/1714342

Comment: Does [`Enumerable.Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) not do what you want? Or do you want a list of just the items that were unique in the list (which is different from what `Distinct()` does)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Faster alternatives to .Distinct()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970983/faster-alternatives-to-distinct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your list an then delete all repeated items, But seems that storing all data in a `Dictionary<string, string>` would be better for this task. Or maybe even put all the list in a `HashSet`.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky why not? class item contains two string fields. `Name` could be key and `Description` is a value, just fits this case

Comment: Actually there was problem with distinct items. Thus I thought you have several items with same name, and appropriate type would be `Dictionary<string, List<Item>>` (or Lookup). But if answer solved problem, then it's of course correct +1

Answer (score 4):

I would opt for Linq, unless or until the performance turns out to be insufficient:

```
var considered = from i in MyCollection
         group i by i.Name into g
         select new { Name = g.Key, Cnt = g.Count(), Instance = g.First() };
var result = from c in considered where c.Cnt == 1 select c.Instance;
```

(Assuming I've interpreted your question correctly as "return those items whose `Name` only appears once in the list")

Comment: That's how I interpreted the question, but it's a little unclear!

Answer (score 2):

i am having java version of the code

```
implement the comparator then define the method as below in Item class

public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2)
{
   // return 0 if objects are equal in terms of your data members such as name or any
}
```

Then use the below code in the class in which MyCollection is defined

```
   HashSet<Item> set1 = new HashSet<Item>();
   set1.addAll(MyCollection);
   MyCollection.clear();
   MyCollection.addAll(set1);
```

This will give you the sorted set

Answer (score 1):

[MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs?r=d4396b9ff63932be0ab07c36452a481d20f96307) has a `DistinctBy` extension that is great for this sort of thing, its open source and just a few lines of code so easy to add to your code.

```
var results = MyCollection.DistinctBy(p => p.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see you found your answer, but you can also do it fairly simply using `Distinct`;

```
internal class NameComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item> {
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y) { return x.Name == y.Name;     }
    public int GetHashCode(Item obj) { return obj.Name.GetHashCode(); }
}

var distinctItems = MyCollection.Distinct(new NameComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var alreadyUsed = new HashSet<TKey>();            
    foreach (var item in sequence)
    {
        var key = keySelector(item);
        if (alreadyUsed.Add(key))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Second is to use `.Distinct()` and override `Equals` in your item to match name